# consultas en php y sql

Tags: php, sql

soy nueva en la programación en php con base de datos en sql, tengo dos cosnultas y necesito que unirlas pues el resultado no es el que necesito. Aqui dejo una parte del código

```
        $targetpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];   
        $limit = 10;                                 
        $page = @$_GET['page'];
        if($page) 
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;         
        else
            $start = 0;
        
      

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, 
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.post_id DESC)AS T1
                                    FROM tbl_post t1
                                    WHERE $limit between 10 and 20"); 
                                    
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, 
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t2.category_id DESC)AS t2
                                    FROM tbl_category t2
                                    WHERE $limit between 10 and 20"); 

        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Desde ahora muy agradecida

Comment: ¿Que errores o problemas te genera la consulta?

Comment: hola muchas gracias por la ayuda pero me da error cuando ejecuto la página Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eecommerce\blog.php:76 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Eecommerce\blog.php(76): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eecommerce\blog.php on line 76

Comment: Si lo que quieres es unir dos tablas mediante una consulta del tipo `UNION` **tienes que escribir/ejecutar una única consulta, no dos**. Para evitar el error *must have an equal number of expressions*  evita usar el `SELECT  *` ... parece que ambas tablas tienen diferente cantidad de columnas. Pon en cada consulta una lista explícita de las columnas.

Answer (score -2):

si lo que quieres es unir las consultas, puedes hacerlo con el comodín `UNION`, este lo que hace es juntar 2 o mas querys (tienen que tener los mismos campos, como las tuyas) para devolver un unico resultado.

Seria algo asi:

> QUERY1 `UNION` QUERY2

O en `php`

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, 
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.post_id DESC)AS T1
                            FROM tbl_post t1
                            WHERE $limit between 10 and 20"
                            UNION
                            SELECT *, 
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t2.category_id DESC)AS t2
                            FROM tbl_category t2
                            WHERE $limit between 10 and 20
                          );
```

Por cierto es muy recomendable quitar el comodin `*`, solo pide los campos que necesites.

Te dejo un link sobre `union`. (es en español) ;)

[sql UNION](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?sqlsen=union)

Comment: hola muchas gracias por la ayuda pero me da error cuando ejecuto la página   Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eecommerce\blog.php:76 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Eecommerce\blog.php(76): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eecommerce\blog.php on line 76

Comment: Hay te indica el error: como te dije en la respuesta, tiene que tener los mismos campos en un union.

Comment: Bueno, aparte de poner negativos, poner un comentario diciendo por que no lo consideráis una respuesta, estaría muy bien....

Comment: hola disculpa no habia podido responder, lo que me explicó me sirvió no me habia percatado de un parámetro q estaba mal escrito. Gracias.

Comment: En ese caso marcalo como respuesta por favor. Gracias